# Testing contents of each item in an array

Tags: javascript

I know I must be doing something stupid, but a quick heads up might help me, please.

I've used several methods to convert a node list into an array. I won't bore you with all the different attempts. Yes I can read out the new array, but trying to check to see if one of the array items contains a specific string pattern fails.

An example:

```
function getthelinks() {
    var nl = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(nl);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var n=arr[i].indexOf(".mov");   // <------- it's this that fails!
    }
}
```

So the idea is to test the links in a page for movie links ending with 'a href' calls to urls of movies in .mov format.

This is so I can send the page reader to a new page, html5 formatted, to see the video instead of downloading it.

So why do I get   `TypeError: nl[i].indexOf is not a function`?

I simply wish to find a fast way to list the a link calls that go direct to movie files in my pages without editing the pages directly.

Many thanks anyone who can show me the stupid error I'm making.

The page with failing line of code removed is here: http://www.microscopy-uk.org.uk/AAA-test-intercept.html

Comment: var n=arr[i] is this an array too?

Comment: Mol, could you solve your problem with any of the answers? You should mark the answer as accepted if it helped.

Comment: Yes. Accepted. I don't see an easy way here of marking a question as accepted. mol

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because you attempted to use `indexOf`, a string method, on an HTML node. You must access the `href` attribute of the node first: `var n = arr[i].href.indexOf(".mov");`.

Moreover, if you just want to know if the url ends with *.mov*, you could use a test like the following:

```
if (arr[i].href.endsWith(".mov")) {
    // Do some magic.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in support of [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2321042/andrew)'s answer which really resolves your case completely.

Additionanly you could find anchor elements with href attributr values that end in *.mov* by following this succinct approach:

```
var movLinks = document.querySelectorAll("[href$=\".mov\"]");
```

That way you wouldn't have a need to loop and filter.